# tensor.numpy() not working in tensorflow.data.Dataset. Throws the error: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1 and python 3.7

First consider the following piece of code where tensor.numpy() works correctly:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.save('data.npy',np.ones(1024))

def func(mystr): 
    return np.load(mystr.numpy())

mystring = tf.constant('data.npy')
print(func(mystring))
```

The above code works correctly and outputs `[1. 1. 1. ... 1. 1. 1.]`.

Now consider the following code in which tensor.numpy() doesn't work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

np.save('data.npy',np.ones(1024))

def func(mystr):
    return np.load(mystr.numpy())

mystring = tf.constant('data.npy')
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([mystring])
data.map(func,1)
```

The above code gives the following error `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

I am unable to figure out why tensor.numpy() doesn't work in the case of tf.data.Dataset.map()

**EDIT**

The following paragraph clarifies my purpose:

I have a dataset folder which contains millions of data pair (image,time-series). The entire dataset wont fit into memory, so I am using the tf.data.Dataset.map(func). Inside the func() function I want to load a numpy file which contains the time series as well as load the image. For loading the image there are inbuilt functions in tensorflow like tf.io.read_file and tf.image.decode_jpeg that accept string tensor. But np.load() does not accept string tensor. Thats why I want to convert the string tensor into a standard python string.

Comment: Why are you using numpy inside  `func` ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have edited my question a bit to make my purpose clear. I have a dataset folder which contains millions of data pair (image,timeseries). The entire dataset wont fit into memory, so I am using the tf.data.Dataset.map(func). Inside the func() function I want to load a numpy file which contains the time series as well as load the image. For loading the image there are inbuilt functions in tensorflow like `tf.io.read_file` and `tf.image.decode_jpeg` that accept string tensor. But np.load() does not accept string tensor. Thats why I want to convert the string tensor into a standard python string.

Answer (score 11):

From the .map() [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1099-L1214):

> irrespective of the context in which map_func is defined (eager vs. graph), tf.data traces the function and executes it as a graph.

To use Python code inside `.map()` you have two options:

1. Rely on AutoGraph to convert Python code into an equivalent graph computation. The downside of this approach is that AutoGraph can convert some but not all Python code.
2. Use `tf.py_function`, which allows you to write arbitrary Python code but will generally result in worse performance than 1).

For example:

```
d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(['hello', 'world'])

#  transform a byte string tensor to a byte numpy string and decode to python str
#  upper case string using a Python function
def upper_case_fn(t):
    return t.numpy().decode('utf-8').upper()

#  use the python code in graph mode
d.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func=upper_case_fn,
      inp=[x], Tout=tf.string))  # ==> [ "HELLO", "WORLD" ]
```

I hope this is still useful.

Comment: Further examples of tf.py_function can be found in the official documentation (tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines), in the section "Applying arbitrary Python logic"

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first example is executed eagerly but that `tf.data.Dataset` are inherently lazily evaluated (with good reason).

A dataset can be used to represent arbitrarily large (and even infinite) datasets so they are only evaluated inside a computation graph to enable data to be passed through in chunks.

This means that eagerly executed methods such as `numpy()` are not available in a dataset pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. If .numpy() is not available, then how do I convert the string tensor into an ordinary string, so that I can use np.load(mystr)

Comment: Seconded! If I can't use .numpy()/.eval() then how do I get the data out of my tensor into a numpy array?